# How can we prove that transitivity implies quasi-transitivity?

Tags: relations

> Let $R$ be a complete binary relation on $U$. $R$ is
>
> - Transitive if for all $x,y,z \in U$, $xRy \land yRz \implies xRz$,
> - Quasi-transitive if for all $x,y,z \in U$, $xPy \land yPz \implies xPz$
>
> Prove that if $R$ is transitive, it is also quasi-transitive.

I haven't come up with a full solution yet but here's my thinking process. If a relation is transitive, then it deals with $xRy$, which means that $x$ is at least as good as $y$. That means that there two scenarios within this: 1) $x P y$, which means that $x$ is strictly better than $y$, 2) $xIy$ which means that $x$ and $y$ are equal. Therefore, if $R$ is transitive and deals with scenario 1, then it also means that $R$ is quasi-transitive. is this understanding correct?

Again, this is not a full-blown solution or proof. I just wanted to explain my thoughts and try to see if I'm on the right track.

Comment: What does $P$ stand for?

Comment: $xPy$ means that $x$ is strictly better than $y$.

Comment: How is "better than" defined?

Comment: It's a way of saying, if I had to choose between $x$ and $y$, I would always choose $x$ and never $y$. $xRy$ is a way of saying "I can choose $x$ and $y$ or $x$ over $y$ but never $y$ over $x$".

Comment: Ah, so "better than" is the relation $R$?

Comment: Yes better than is $R$ and strictly better than is $P$.

Answer (score 2):

From your discussion and the context I take it that $R$ is a preorder (also called a quasiorder), i.e., a transitive, reflexive relation, and $x\mathrel{P}y$ is equivalent to $x\mathrel{R}y$ **and** $y\not\mathrel{R}x$. Your $x\mathrel{I}y$ is then $x\mathrel{R}y$ **and** $y\mathrel{R}x$, the *indifference* relation on $U$.

Suppose that $R$ is transitive and that $x,y,z\in U$ are such that $x\mathrel{P}y$ and $y\mathrel{P}z$. Then $x\mathrel{R}y$ and $y\mathrel{R}z$, so $x\mathrel{R}z$. To show that $x\mathrel{P}z$, we must show that $z\not\mathrel{R}x$. Suppose, on the contrary, that $z\mathrel{R}x$; then by transitivity $z\mathrel{R}y$. But $y\mathrel{P}z$, so in fact $z\not\mathrel{R}y$. Thus, $z\not\mathrel{R}x$, so $x\mathrel{P}z$, and $R$ is quasi-transitive.